# Python 3.6 What does "if a and " mean?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand another person's Python 3.6 code. This code is supposed to find the number of local minimums and maximums in a list of numbers.

```
input()

a = b = s = 0

for c in map(int, input().split()):

    if a and (a > b < c or a < b > c): s += 1

    a, b = b, c

print(s)
```

The first input line contains one integer, the number `n` of elements in the list. 
The second input line contains the `n` integers that are the elements of the list.

So for example if the input is:

> 4
>
> 1 5 2 4

the output should be 2.

Can someone please explain what the `if a and` part means? I understand that `if (a > b < c or a < b > c):` mean "if this is true do the following", but what does `if a and` do?

Comment: You put brackets the wrong way. Python interprets it as: `if (a and (a > b < c or a < b > c)):`...

Comment: `a and` is part of the expression that `if` is testing. There is no special `if a and` syntax.  **Everything** after `if` and before `:` is the expression being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 0 equal to False, and 1 equal to True. So if value of a is 1 condition will be valid.

Comment: Any non-zero number is also True. And they are not *equal*, they *evaled as*

Comment: "_evaled_" is the wrong word. The boolean values `True` and `False` are subclassed from integers. You can check that with `isinstance(True, int)`.

Comment: @Matthias, doesn't matter, because 2 != True

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov: Right. `2` is not `True`. It's just _trueish_ if used like this: `if 2:`.

Comment: @Matthias, I do not argue with this and that's what I meant by "evaled"

Answer (score 0):

`if(<condition>)` runs the code block after it, IF the condition is evaluated to true.

The expression `a and <condition>` works the following way. It evaluates `a` and if that evaluates to something that can be interpreted as true, it returns the value of `<condition>`. Otherwise it returns `a`.

An example

```
>>> 1 and 3
3
>>> 0 and 3
0
```

This means that the if block will be run if `a` is not zero and if `(a > b < c or a < b > c)` evaluates to true.